# Disable impersonation of a group, or for a realm within KeyCloak?

Tags: keycloak

KeyCloak question for everyone.

Is it possible to disable impersonation of a group (for example, an admin group), or for a realm (the admin management console)?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign impersonation role for a user from `Client Roles` of the realm.

Each realm has a built-in client called `realm-management`. This client defines client-level roles that specify permissions that can be granted to manage the realm.

You can find more on available roles from [Keycloak docs](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_per_realm_admin_permissions)

Once you remove `impersonation` client-level role for your realm , it is not available for all users of the realm.